# Expectation of of joint probability distribution

Tags: probability

We have defined for discrete random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ the expectation:

$$E[\phi (X_1,...,X_n)] = \sum_{x_1} \sum_{x_2}...\sum_{x_n}\phi(x_1,...,x_n)p(x_1,...,x_n)$$ where $p(.)$ is the joint probability mass function.

I am trying to understand what this definition means, and as such I am trying to show if $\phi(X_1,...,X_n) = X_1$ that this definition should reduce to $\sum_{x_1} x_1 p_{X_1}(x_1)$, however I am having trouble showing this. Could someone please help

Comment: This formula is not a definition. The definition is $E[X] = \sum _x xP(X = x)$. It is a theorem that $E[f(X)] = \sum _x f(x)P(X = x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the simplest case where $X_{i}$ are discrete random variables. In this case we can explicitly write down everything in a few cases.

Let $X, Y$ be two biased fat coins with probability $0.3/0.7$ of head and tail respectively. Then individually you have
$$
E(X)=E(Y)=0.3*1+0.7*0=0.3
$$
But you can also calculate it in a different way. Rather than viewing $X,Y$ as separate random variables, you can think $X,Y$ as components of a bi-variable $Z=(X,Y)$. Now $Z$ takes four values:
$$
P(Z=(0,0))=0.49, P(Z=(0,1))=P(Z=(1,0))=0.21, P(Z=(1,1))=0.09
$$
If we want to recover the expectation of $X$, we want to consider it over all possible cases of $Y$'s value available. Therefore now we have
$$
E(X)=0.09*1+0.49*0+0*0.21+1*0.21=0.3
$$
because over individual cases we should have 
$$
P(X=x)=\sum_{y}P(X=x, Y=y)
$$
and the equality follows. For your one variable case, since the possible values for other random variables are empty, you get the formula for free.

Comment: Very clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is simply the intuitive definition of an expectation.  To find the expected value of a function $\varphi$, you merely sum over all possible values of the variables weighted by the probability those variable values appear, i.e., $p( x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, times the function evaluated at those values.  If the expected value is merely a function of the first variable, it can arise if you marginalize over the other variables (i.e., integrate or sum over them).

Comment: I'm sorry, if (going by my example) we have just one variable $X_1$ then I'm not sure how $E(X_1) = \sum_{x_1}...\sum_{x_n} x_1 p(x_1,...,x_n)$ reduces to $\sum_{x_1} x_1 p_{X_1}(x_1)$ which is the usual definition